# How can I "highlight" a DOM element using its corresponding highlighted Dygraph series?

Tags: dygraphs

How can I reference and modify an element outside my Dygraph object based on the selected series?  In the example below (for which I've created a [JSFiddle mock-up](http://jsfiddle.net/KJBmK/1/)), the "Bam-Bam" series is currently highlighted, so I want to increase the text-size of Bam-Bam's label in the characters list from 1.0em to 1.1em.  Do I want to set up a listener function to track changes to *getHighlightSeries*?  Then what?

[image: Image of example Dygraph]

Thanks in advance!

```
<p/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected series gets a "highlight" class in the legend. You can use this to style it however you like. See http://dygraphs.com/tests/series-highlight.html for a few examples.

Comment: Thanks @danvk, for the quick response.  I re-reviewed the series-highlight examples, and believe I understand how you are setting or toggling the highlight attribute for labels within Dygraph.  However, I still don't seem to understand if or how to toggle the "highlight" state for elements outside of Dygraph (e.g., the individual labels in my "Character List".  Can you point me to an example of such?

Comment: If you want to do anything really fancy with the legend, you should get rid of the built-in one and create your own using highlightCallback, unhighlightCallback and the public API: http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html

Answer (score 0):

To highlight ***both*** the current Dygraph series ***and*** its corresponding series name, I followed [Dan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388951/danvk) advice and placed a call inside the *[un]highlightCallback(s)* to toggle the Emphasis style for the current series label.

I also directed the Dygraph labels to a hidden div, and generated my own labels.  This allowed me to: a) use the ticker label rather than the y-axis value; and b) add my action verb ("at" or "to") to describe if the character had moved from their previous location.

I've update the [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/KJBmK/7/) to reflect this solution.

Here's a purty picture of the finished product:
[image: demo of Dygraph project]